# how do i get zoom on a raspberry pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, software-installation, ubuntu

I am looking to install zoom web conferencing on my raspberry pi 4 4gb running Ubuntu mate 20.04.
I have tried the pi kiss method but pi kiss wont load.

How do i do this?

Comment: this looks like an Ubuntu question, not RPi question

Comment: Its still the pi4 though

Comment: so, if you run Ubuntu on an HP laptop, and you have trouble installing zoom, then you would go to an HP website for help, not Ubuntu site?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rv4vfRLbYmU

Comment: Ive already tried that method

Comment: Have you tried to search for a solution?